# How long will eggless pasta dough last in the fridge?

Tags: storage-lifetime, pasta, dough

I made some fresh pasta for myself, but the recipe made double the amount I need. I didn't have time to make the rest of the pasta and dry it, so I just wrapped the dough ball in plastic wrap and stuck it in the fridge.

How long will the dough last in the fridge?

I can probably use it tomorrow or in the next 2 days.

The recipe is basically 2 cups flour, 1/2 cup water, no eggs. I used half white whole wheat, half AP, tbsp of olive oil. (Yes it's very good, even w/just some olive oil, parmesan, salt and pepper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul,

I make my own pasta dough frequently.  Since my standard recipe makes around 40oz (1 kg) of dough, I always have leftover, so I've had plenty of experience with saving it.

Even with eggs, pasta dough will be fine in the fridge for a week; the texture will be unaffected (if anything, it will be better).  If you want to keep it longer than a week, it can be frozen for several weeks wrapped tightly in plastic wrap, and more-or-less indefinitely if you vacuum-seal it.

Glad to hear about your WWW recipe, I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly: there is nothing in the recipe that will go bad in two days. I am unsure whether the texture will be affected after two days in the refrigerator. But make sure the dough is wrapped tightly. The most common way to store fresh pasta is to freeze it. Tell you what, make an experiment: Freeze half and refrigerate the other. Then after two days compare the cook both and tell us whether is a difference or not.

Answer (score 1):

It was fine the next day. It was a little less stretchy, but that might have been because it was a little cold and I didn't let it get all the way to room temperature before running it through the machine, so it got some holes in it. It worked fine after running it through a few times on the largest setting, and tasted pretty much the same.